# Convert Oracle MD5 to MySQL or Ruby

Tags: mysql, oracle, md5

I have the following Oracle function that is used for checking user passwords, but I want to switch to MySQL. I'm looking for a set of MySQL functions that will produce the equivalent result.

```
FUNCTION encpasswd (ID IN VARCHAR, passwd IN VARCHAR)

   RETURN VARCHAR

IS

   v_result   VARCHAR2 (4000);

BEGIN

   v_result := DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.md5 (input_string => ID || passwd);

   --RETURN RAWTOHEX (v_result);

   RETURN v_result;

END encpasswd;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert NVARCHAR2 to MD5 Hash in Oracle DBMS\_OBFUSCATION\_TOOLKIT.MD5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827888/convert-nvarchar2-to-md5-hash-in-oracle-dbms-obfuscation-toolkit-md5)

Comment: Thanks. Not a dupe of that question because I'm trying to convert an oracle MD5 function into a MySQL MD5 function.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's *MD5* function returns a string of 32 hexadecimal characters. It's marked as a binary string but it isn't the 16 byte binary data one would expect.

So to fix it, this string must be converted back to the binary data for example:

```
SELECT hex(aes_encrypt('test-data', unhex(MD5('test_key'))));
```

The result is:

```
8FCA326C25C8908446D28884394F2E22
```

[SQLFiddle for MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43499/2)

It's again a string of 32 hexadecimal characters. But otherwise it's the same result as with Oracle.

And BTW:

- MySQL uses PKCS7 padding.
- PKCS5 padding and PKCS7 padding are one and the same. So the Oracle padding option is correct.
- MySQL uses ECB block cipher mode. So you'll have to adapt the code accordingly. (It doesn't make any difference for the first 16 bytes.)
- MySQL uses no initialization vector (the same as your Oracle code).
- MySQL uses a non-standard folding a keys. So to achieve the same result in MySQL and Oracle (or .NET or Java), only use keys that are 16 byte long.

Comment: So in this case, if id=1 and passwrd=foo, what would the statement look like? 
SELECT hex(aes_encrypt('1', unhex(MD5('foo'))));

Comment: Yes. More likely. You can test it in your oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has a native "md5" function.

```
SELECT md5(concat(id, passwd)) FROM yourtable
```

As a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `encpasswd`(`ID` VARCHAR(250), `passwd` VARCHAR(250)) RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
BEGIN
    RETURN md5(concat(ID,passwd))
END
```